# what is Native Android with java?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I'm new in android development and I was told to learn how to make these applications by native android with java in my job.

I was doing some research and I got confused because I see there's a kit called Android Studio but also others sites say that native android is about c/c++ and something called NDK, but nobody told me about that in my job, so I really don't know what they mean when they talk about native android, I need to start learning about native Android with java, and I'm not sure what it means.

What does it means android native with java? Is it related to c++ too? Or does native just mean java?

Comment: 'native' is ambiguous. First meaning: "the way which is recommended and designed for a platform" - Java in this case. Second meaning: "developed in language, which is compiled to native CPU instructions" - which are C/C++. If you were asked for "native Android app with java" - I think they meant Java, not C and C++.

Comment: Don't be scared to ask the person what they meant. But based on your comments in the answers and the fact they referenced Java, they probably mean to not use web-based frameworks.

Comment: Native is ambiguous but to me (in this context) it means an app written in Java against the official SDK (as opposed to something written against a third party framework that compiles to multiple platforms). It doesn't imply use of the NDK. Don't be afraid to ask them what they meant - based on your other comment regarding "better performance", its possible they aren't clear on the definition themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SDK is in Java but the NDK is in C++.

Google said don't choose one among other for performance reasons (or any other) and use the one you prefer and you feel more comfortable.

Don't get confused by the word native and write your app in the language you need at that moment.

Comment: what they told me is that we need to program native android applications because if they are native without any framework then we can get a better performance and stuff like that in our applications.

Comment: If you are using NDK or the SDK the app is native

Answer (score 2):

I think Java is default developing language for Android. There are Qt libraries for Android which are in written in C\C++. But if they told you in company to get know with java so i think you should do this.